# Dynamic Data Lists Display Template

Tags: liferay-6

I tried to add a link for delete an entry of my data lists respective to [tutorial1](https://www.liferay.com/de/documentation/liferay-portal/6.2/user-guide/-/ai/make-it-pretty-creating-custom-displays-liferay-portal-6-2-user-guide-10-en) and [tutorial2](http://www.opensourceforlife.com/2012/08/generate-portleturl-inside-liferay.html) but I missed something.

```
   <h1>Task Summary</h1>

Hallo "${reserved_record_set_name}".

<#assign DDLRecordLocalService = serviceLocator.findService("com.liferay.portlet.dynamicdatalists.service.DDLRecordLocalService")>
<#assign groupService = serviceLocator.findService("com.liferay.portal.service.GroupLocalService")>
<#assign layoutService = serviceLocator.findService("com.liferay.portal.service.LayoutLocalService")>

<#assign records = DDLRecordLocalService.getRecords(reserved_record_set_id)>

<ul>
<#if records?has_content>
        <#list records as cur_record>
                <li><em>${cur_record.getFieldValue("Author", locale)}</em> will help with 
                <a href="${ddmUtil.getDisplayFieldValue(themeDisplay, cur_record.getFieldValue("DataSet", locale), cur_record.getFieldType("DataSet"))}">${languageUtil.format(locale, "download-x", "Data Set")}</a>




                <#assign controlPanelGroup = groupService.getGroup(portalUtil.getDefaultCompanyId(), "Control Panel")>
                <#assign controlPanelPlid = layoutService.getDefaultPlid(controlPanelGroup.getGroupId(), true)>

                <#assign portletActionURL = portletURLFactory.create(request,"167",controlPanelPlid,"ACTION_PHASE")>

                ${portletActionURL.setParameter("recordId", "${cur_record.getRecordId()}")}
                ${portletActionURL.setParameter("cmd", "delete")}
                ${portletActionURL.setParameter("struts_action", "/dynamic_data_lists/edit_record")}
                ${portletActionURL.setParameter("redirect", "${themeDisplay.getPortalURL()}${themeDisplay.getURLCurrent()}")}

                <#if permissionChecker.hasPermission(scopeGroupId, "com.liferay.portlet.dynamicdatalists.model.DDLRecordSet", "${reserved_record_set_id}", "DELETE")>                
                    <form action="${portletActionURL}" method="POST">
                        <input type="submit" value="Delete">
                    </form>
                </#if>
               </li>
        </#list>
</#if>
```

This is how the view looks like 
[image: view]

and after I click the delete button I get a error [image: error]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's quite an interesting case, it took me some time to figure it out. This code works for me (on 6.2 CE GA2):

```
<#assign controlPanelGroup = groupService.getGroup(portalUtil.getDefaultCompanyId(), "Control Panel")>
<#assign controlPanelPlid = layoutService.getDefaultPlid(controlPanelGroup.getGroupId(), true)>

<#assign portletActionURL = portletURLFactory.create(request,"167",controlPanelPlid,"ACTION_PHASE")>
${portletActionURL.setParameter("recordId", "${cur_record.getRecordId()}")}
${portletActionURL.setParameter("cmd", "delete")}
${portletActionURL.setParameter("struts_action", "/dynamic_data_lists/edit_record")}
${portletActionURL.setParameter("redirect", "${themeDisplay.getPortalURL()}${themeDisplay.getURLCurrent()}")}

<#if permissionChecker.hasPermission(scopeGroupId, "com.liferay.portlet.dynamicdatalists.model.DDLRecordSet", "${reserved_record_set_id}", "DELETE")>                
    <form action="${portletActionURL}" method="POST">
        <input type="submit" value="Delete">
    </form>
</#if>
```

The request has to go via POST, otherwise Liferay will print `This URL can only be invoked using POST` to the logs. That's why it is a form (but you can naturally submit form with the link).

Comment: many thx, do you have an idee how to use the permission service? I always get the error `serviceLocator.findService("com.liferay.portlet.dynamicdatalists.service.permission.DDLRecordSetPermission") is undefined.`

Comment: Sure, I updated my answer with permission verification.

Comment: ` ${portletActionURL.setParameter("redirect", "${themeDisplay.getPortalURL()}.${themeDisplay.getURLCurrent()}")}` redirects to Site Administration->Content->Dynamic Data Lists and the entrie is not deleted.

Comment: In my case, there is a DDL portlet put on a standard liferay page, all entries are listed and each of them has Delete button (generated by the code above). After clicking that button, entry is being deleted and user is redirected back to the same page with DDL portlet (thanks to the `redirect` parameter). What is your final Delete URL (generated by the template)?.

Comment: The view is the same you described. If I click the delete button, the entry does not deleted and the its redirected to "Site Administration->Content" `http://localhost:8080/group/control_panel/manage?p_auth=hMKF6dWl&p_p_auth=lXK8yjMB&p_p_id=167&p_p_lifecycle=1&p_p_col_id=column-2&p_p_col_count=2&_167_recordId=21316&_167_cmd=delete&_167_struts_action=%2Fdynamic_data_mapping_list%2Fedit_record&_167_redirect=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080.%2Fwelcome2`

Comment: You have wrong struts action path (`dynamic_data_mapping_list` in your case vs `dynamic_data_lists` in my), double check if you copied the code properly.

Comment: First I tried your version, but then I checked that parameter `struts_action` in the record_action.jsp is `<portlet:param name="struts_action" value="/dynamic_data_mapping_list/edit_record" />`.

Comment: First I tried with `dynamic_data_mapping_list`, but it seems that it's some old stuff. In 6.2 there is `dynamic_data_lists`:https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/6.2.1-ga2/portal-web/docroot/WEB-INF/struts-config.xml#L614-L617.

Comment: I don't have any GA1 at hand at the moment, maybe there is some bug. Check how it works with GA2. Anyway, what is in your logs?

Comment: You mean `C:\liferay-portal-6.2.0-ce-ga1\logs\liferay.2014-07-01.log`, there are no entries with a significant timestamp.

Comment: I found only `catalina.2014-07-01.log` and no related timestamp.

Comment: Then I don't know, it works for me very well. The URL you pasted is the same as in my case (except for struts action path and `p_p_col_id/count`). The only thing which is different is liferay version, try to check how it behaves in 6.2 ga2.

Comment: Same behavior in 6.2 ga2. If I click the delete button for the entry I added first of all, then nothing happen and for the rest in the list I get the same error. But if I restart the server the entry is deleted.

Comment: Then I don't know what can be wrong, for me it works very well. I would check if there is everything OK with your environment, maybe you have installed some hooks/ext modifying standard liferay behaviour.

Comment: The 6.2 ga2 was new downloaded. Could you please post the whole src code of your template, which is running on your system? How does you portal-ext.properties file looks like?

Comment: Hmm, I think I can see where is the error. The `redirect` parameter should be without dot in the middle: `${themeDisplay.getPortalURL()}${themeDisplay.getURLCurrent()}`. I don't know where did it came from :) I will fix my answer in a moment.

Comment: I see that there is also some issue with first element of a list (the form is not generated). But I'm afraid it is some Liferay javascript magic, and requires some further investingation. The other elements are delete without any problems.

Comment: Ok, the problem with first element is cause by the fact that Liferay surrounds whole DDL with own form tag (don't know why). That's why there should be no other embedded forms as it this causes HTML to be invalid. I don't know why but in this case the browser/liferay JS removes the first delete form element and leaves only the input button. I made a workaround by putting `<form action="#" method="POST"><input type="hidden" value="something"></form>` at the top of the template, but it is definately not good, you can investigate further, maybe some javascript will work here?

Comment: Many thx, could I use also organize the delete functionality by using `<liferay-ui:icon`?

Comment: How can I add some Java script libraries to this Display-Template?

Comment: Hmm, I would add them to Theme rather than directly to script, but it depends on your requirement - if it is related strictly to the list or generally with the project. Answer to previous comment is no, you cannot use taglibs in templates, but as far as I remember liferay-ui:icon generates some html element with proper css class - it should be easy to add this manually.

Comment: "...to add them to Theme..." does that mean to write a hook for `/html/common/themes/top_js.jspf` or `/html/portal/init.jsp` or should I change theme(portal_normal.vm)?

Comment: No, don't use hooks for that. I assumed that you have a custom theme created strictly for yout project. Usually, when you create a new portal, you don't use standard Liferay theme (classic), but you create your own based on client's requirements. Then you put all css/javascript stuff to that theme and then use it in your portlets/templates and other customizations.

Comment: Is it possible to change the Form-Template in a way that I can add files by browsing on my local machine? Till now I can only select files from my current Document and Media area. It would be useful that I could add a element like Document and Media to my form, which I can configure to save the uploaded file in a specific place in the Dokument and Media portlet. Can I do so with the HTML Element?

Comment: You want to read files from your local machine and display them on DDL form, or rather save form-submitted documents to your local disc? DDL mechanism allows you to create simple lists, if you have any more sophisticated requirements, try to create new portlet for that.

Comment: I used DDL to create a Form and display the uploaded information in a custom Template. To select files via Form I can use the Document and Media element. What I like to have is a element like File Upload, where I can upload a file through the form directly into the D&M portlet. I found a website there is a picture for Manage Data in the DDL, which contains a small icon in the 4th picture for a [File-Upload](http://blogs.xtivia.com/home/-/blogs/make-your-dynamic-data-list-more-powerf-1) element.

Comment: I also like to add a form for the update function to my template, how to translate `<portlet:param name="formDDMTemplateId" value="<%= String.valueOf(formDDMTemplateId) %>" />` from the record_action.jsp? I tried to asssign `<#assign GetterUtil = serviceLocator.findService("com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.GetterUtil")>` but serviceLocator cannot be assigned GetterUtil

Comment: I think that should be posted as a next question. Why did you unaccept the answer?

Comment: Because I thought, that you dont get a notification for the new comment if the answer checked as accepted. I posted the other question [here](https://www.liferay.com/de/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/40367888)

Comment: I get the notifications. I just may have a lot of work at that moment. I post on StackOverflow usually if I got some spare time :)

Comment: Ok, I thought if you would see the comment it takes just a second for you to figure it out, because the call is similar too the other I cant see why this class could not be loaded.