# Liferay Template for DDL

Tags: liferay-6

Under Site-Administration->Content->Dynamic Data Lists-> Manage Data Definition->Manage Templates I like to create a new Freemaker template. In this template I like to call the class GetterUtil:

```
 <#assign DDLRecordLocalService = serviceLocator.findService("com.liferay.portlet.dynamicdatalists.service.DDLRecordLocalService")>

<#assign GetterUtil = serviceLocator.findService("com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.GetterUtil")>
```

If I do so I get the following error:

> serviceLocator.findService("com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.GetterUtil")
>   is undefined.
>       It cannot be assigned to GetterUtil

At the end I want to call

```
  long formDDMTemplateId = GetterUtil.getLong((String)row.getParameter("formDDMTemplateId"));
```

in my DDL Template. This line comes from dynamic_data_lists/record_action.jsp.

Is the object row equal to the object cur_record from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24492606/dynamic-data-lists-display-template/24495946?noredirect=1#comment38747424_24495946) post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GetterUtil is not Liferay Service, it's just an util class. Inside DDL template it is bound as a `getterUtil` variable, eg: `getterUtil.getString("asdf")`.

Comment: thx, I edit my start post, because I have a additional question to that. I need to add this parameter <portlet:param name="formDDMTemplateId" value="<%= String.valueOf(formDDMTemplateId) %>" /> to the ActionURL in the DDL Template. Where you find the binding?